# Dockerized elasticsearch and fscrawler: failed to create elasticsearch client, disabling crawler… Connection refused

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, fscrawler

I received the following error when attempting to connect Dockerized fscrawler to Dockerized elasticsearch:

> [f.p.e.c.f.c.ElasticsearchClientManager] failed to create
> elasticsearch client, disabling crawler… 
> [f.p.e.c.f.FsCrawler] Fatal
> error received while running the crawler: [Connection refused]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When fscrawler is run for the fist time (i.e., `docker-compose run fscrawler`) it creates `/config/{fscrawer_job}/_settings.yml` with the following default setting:

```
elasticsearch:
  nodes:
  - url: "http://127.0.0.1:9200"
```

This will cause fscrawler to attempt to connect to localhost (i.e., 127.0.0.1). However, this will fail when fscrawler is located within a docker container because it is attempting to connect with the localhost of the CONTAINER. This was particularly confusing in my case because elasticsearch WAS accessible as localhost, but on the localhost of my physical computer (and NOT localhost of the container). Changing the url allowed fscrawler to connect to network address where elasticsearch actually resides.

```
elasticsearch:
  nodes:
  - url: "http://elasticsearch:9200"
```

I used the following docker image: https://hub.docker.com/r/toto1310/fscrawler

```
# FILE: docker-compose.yml

version: '2.2'
services:
  # FSCrawler 
  fscrawler:
    image: toto1310/fscrawler
    container_name: fscrawler
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/config:/root/.fscrawler
      - ${PWD}/data:/tmp/es
    networks: 
      - esnet
    command: fscrawler job_name

  # Elasticsearch Cluster
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.3.2
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch
      - discovery.seed_hosts=elasticsearch2
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch,elasticsearch2
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - esnet
  elasticsearch2:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.3.2
    container_name: elasticsearch2
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch2
      - discovery.seed_hosts=elasticsearch
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch,elasticsearch2
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet

volumes:
  esdata01:
    driver: local
  esdata02:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
```

Ran `docker-compose up elasticsearch elasticsearch2`
to bring up elasticsearch nodes. 
Ran `docker-compose run fscrawler` to create `_settings.yml`

Edited `_settings.yml` to

```
elasticsearch:
  nodes:
  - url: "http://elasticsearch:9200"
```

Started fscrawler `docker-compose up fscrawler`